# Search user engine with Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, search

I want to implement a search user engine on my app. It is writen with swift and has a Firebase backend. The problem is that I don't find any help on the web.
My data is structured like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7qbT.png

I tried with this code and others, but still don't working:

```
Database.database().reference().queryOrdered(byChild: "fullname").queryEqual(toValue: "michel dupond").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            print("Snapshot:", snapshot as? [String: String])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will your search always contain a full name? If you want to implement something like `contains(value: String)` I'd recommend using [Algolia](http://algolia.com) to add string searches.